# ASP:LinkButton and Eval

Tags: asp.net, gridview, linkbutton, templatefield

I'm using an ASP:LinkButton inside of an ItemTemplate inside of a TemplateField in a GridView. For the command argument for the link button I want to pass the ID of the row from the datasource that the gridview is bound to, so I'm doing something like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="viewLogButton" CommandName="viewLog" CommandArgument="<%#Eval("ID")%>" Text="View Log" runat="server"/>
```

Unfortunately, the resulting HTML is this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="viewLogButton" CommandName="viewLog" CommandArgument="3" Text="View Log" runat="server"/>
```

It seems that it *is* parsing the Eval() properly, but this is somehow causing it *not* to parse the LinkButton tag and just dump it out as literal text. Does anyone know:

a) why this is happening and,
b) what a good solution to this problem is?

Comment: "<%#Eval("ID")%>" looks hard to parse.

Comment: Can you post some code. It sounds like your LinkButton might be caught within an Literal control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it may not be causing it, I usually define it like this:

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>'
```

Please post the rest of the GridView's markup, as it shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: silly me, I guess the quotes did it. Thanks. I assumed that all the templates were parsed before the actual asp:* markup - guess not.

Comment: Just had the same problem and was about to ask the same question.

Comment: what would I do without StackOverflow!

Comment: sir @eglasius i have the same problem can you help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499531/gridview-row-command-not-working