# get value from string or store in database?

Tags: asp.net, button, gridview, boundfield, rowcommand

this is my viewcreditrequest html page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>

           <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
            SortExpression="Username" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
            SortExpression="LastName" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
            SortExpression="FirstName" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
            SortExpression="CompanyName" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="EmailAddress" 
            SortExpression="EmailAddress" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyAddress" HeaderText="CompanyAddress" 
            SortExpression="CompanyAddress" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="IncomeRange" HeaderText="IncomeRange" 
            SortExpression="IncomeRange" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreditRequest" HeaderText="CreditRequest" 
            SortExpression="CreditRequest" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactNumber" HeaderText="ContactNumber" SortExpression="ContactNumber" />

        <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Approve" CommandName="Approve" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CreditRequest") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["IslandGasAdminFM"] != null)
            {

                bindgrid();
                Label1.Text = "- Finance Manager";

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Finance Manager credentials needed'); window.location.href='LogIn.aspx';</script>");
            }
        }
    }


    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

        if (e.CommandName == "Approve")
        {
            string creditRequest = e.CommandArgument as string;
        }
    }
    public void bindgrid()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from CreditRequests ", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from CreditRequests", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "data");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

what i want to happen here is to get the value of "credit request" in the boundfield. The bindgrid() is working fine, also i have added

```
EnableViewState="false"
```

to my gridview. When i click on the button, it now assigns the value of credit request to string credit request. any idea on how can i make it visible or even store it in database?

Comment: Yesterday we had a long chat and eventually got the GridView1_RowCommand to work.I even gave you step by step instructions how to use the debugger and you said the GridView1_RowCommand is now being hit when you click on "Approve".So what is not working now?

Comment: its working now but not showing any result sir. it should have the credit request value right? @DenisWessels

Comment: What do you mean by "result"?The credit request value will be isnide the creditRequest string variable.You need to write code now to take that value and insert it into the database or do any other processing that you require

Comment: can you guide me pls sir @DenisWessels

Comment: google "insert value in sql database asp.net C#"

Comment: how d i get the vlue from the credit request string?

Comment: any idea will do @DenisWessels

Comment: still there? @DenisWessels really need you on this